# View is taking much time to give resultset than the same query used in the view definition?

Tags: sql-server-2012

We have SQL Server Enterprise edition running on a high end machine.

We have a view with multiple joins. When I run the same query which is used for view definition, it is giving output in secs.

But if I run the view using

```
select * from view
```

it is taking a lot of time... considerately more than an hour...

If you query

```
select x, y, z 
from table1 
where id = x
```

it executes in seconds.

If you query:

```
create view vw_tmp as 
   select x, y, z 
   from table1 

select x, y, z 
from vw_tmp 
where id = x
```

it is taking more than an hour ...

I tried in different ways.. but did not work..

We are not using indexes as we need to deal to huge insertions every time.
If indexes could be the solution, why this view definition is working fine as a separate query?...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Try examining the execution plans of each query.  "We are not using indexes"  Are you saying you're not even using primary keys?

Comment: Yes we don't have  any keys..I tried through estimated execution plan..checking with actual execution plan now..Even though did not have clue how the same query is has variant execution time...I tried using refresh and recompile an remove cache..still no difference..

Answer (score 0):

> Views are primarily used for convenience and security, not for speed
>   improvements.
>
> That said, SQL Server 2000 and above do have a special feature called
>   Indexed Views that can greatly improve performance, but you have to
>   create indexed views following a [very specific set of guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx).

try it like this

```
create view vw_tmp as 
   select x, y, z 
   from table1 **WITH(NOLOCK)**

select x, y, z 
from vw_tmp 
where id = x
```

Comment: yes..we did not looking for any speed improvement...minimum we can expect  the approximately similar execution time when compared to the same query executed seperatly...am i wrong?